# erro box vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estou tendo um problema no vagrant ao iniciar a box. Quando dou um vagrant up.

Veja no github os erro que ocorrem.
https://github.com/thiagohumble/ruby/blob/master/ecanalinfo

Informa que está desatualizado sendo que o virtual box está atualizado, assim como o Extension Pack atualizados.

Após dar o vagrant ssh não consigo visualizar o gemfile para iniciar o servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No log que vc informou, o vagrant está procurando por pacotes 32bits, mas o repositório que está configurado para atualizar os pacotes do ubuntu fornece apenas pacotes 64bits.

A próxima linha é o que aparece no seu log que me induz a pensar nisso:

```
Failed to fetch http://apt.hellobits.com/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

Se você baixar o arquivo indicado na URL do log, vai ver que o repositório fornece apenas pacotes `main/binary-amd64`, mas não existem entradas `main/binary-i386`.

Ao invés de utilizar um box 32bits, utilize um 64bits. Isso deve resolver seu problema.

Comment: Batata, sim foi isso mesmo. Obrigado Bruno.